# In Magento 2.3.x How to add dependent Customer Attribute

Tags: magento2.3, customer-attribute

In Magento 2.3.x, How to add dependent Customer Attribute.

It means Need to add 2 attributes like

1. yes/no option
2. Textbox (Based on the option selected)

Comment: @ShafeelSha In Magento 2.3.3 I cant see that option.

Comment: try this https://webkul.com/blog/depend-attribute-field-attributes-field-admin-form-magento2/

Comment: @ShafeelSha Okay. But it is for Product form not for customer.

Comment: I think you need to customize